# Оставить в строке по одному пробелу после слов и по два после каждого конца предложений

Tags: c++, строки

Функции на вход передается строка. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы в этой строке между словами оставался один пробел, а между предложениями-2.

Есть функция

```
void Replace(string s)
{
    s.replace(1, s.find(+" "), " ");
    s.replace(   s.find(". "), "  ");
    cout << s;
}
```

Первый реплейс оставляет в строке везде по одному пробелу, а вот как составить второй так, чтобы он и из строки ничего не вырывал и после точек по два пробела оставлял-я, если честно не догадываюсь, хотя задача предельно тривиальная.

Comment: самым разумным, ИМХО, будет использование regex для этих целей. Понадобится две штуки - на каждый описанный случай

Answer (score 2):

Посредством функций членов  std::string, можно сделать, но не так то просто. Во первых постоянно нужно проверить не закончилась ли строка? Во вторых нужно искать не с самого начала, а с того места где удалили, и учесть количество удаленных элементов. Если учесть также, что предложение может закончится не только точкой, то  чтобы оставить между предложениями по два пробела, придется написать код типа:

```
size_t  p = s.find(' ',s.find_first_of(".?!")),
        q{},  k{};
while (p != s.npos) {
    //ищем начало следующего предложения
    q = s.find_first_not_of(' ', ++p); 
    //новое предложение всегда начинается с большой буквы       
    if (q != s.npos && isupper(s[q])) {
        k = q - p;
        //если после первого пробела больше одного пробела 
        if (k > 1) {
            s.erase(p, --k); 
            //после удаления, индекс начала 
            //следующего предложения уменьшится на k - 1
            q -= k;               
        }
    }
    //ищем конец следующего предложения
    p = s.find(' ', s.find_first_of(".?!", q));        
}
```